# What software supports creation of EPUB (Kindle) files in Persian language based on Amazon RTL file creation standards

Tags: epub

I am trying to develop a file in EPUB format in Persian (Farsi) language based on the Amazon's file creation standards. Could you kindly suggest what software I need to use for this purpose?

I have created my source file in Word 2013 (DOCX format). I saved it as PDF and then tried to use it in Calibre to convert it into the EPUB format but the results were not good at all. The fonts were substituted, paragraphs contained different formats, images were not come through, and Where combination of English and Persian words were used they were out of alignment.

I appreciate any suggestions and help that anyone familiar with the process could offer.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Going from docx to pdf loses information - try docx directly to epub

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It has been helpful but I need further elaboration to be able to create the EPUB format . My aim is to produce an EPUB3 file (Kindle) according to IngramSpark (design arm of Amazon) to place it in the Amazon site. In addition support for Kindle, I would like to set the "page setup" options in "Convert file" menu so that it can be opened by any EPUB reader including Amazon Kindle devices.  setting in my DOCX file across when converting it to the EPUB3 format. Also, not sure what settings I use

Comment: Amazon Kindle is not an EPUB device it can't read EPUB. Also EPUB devices cannot read books from Amazon. Given your mixing up of EPUB, Kindle formats anmd PDF I would suggest it can't be answered here as there are several issues here.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It has been helpful when I uploaded DOCX into Calibre for converting into EPUB with readable Persian fonts too. However, I need further help on settings file conversion parameters for creating a nicely formatted EPUB suitable for Amazon Kindle and other readers. My aim is to produce an EPUB3 file (Kindle) according to Amazon's IngramSpark standards to place it in the Amazon site. Also, I am not sure how to setup my input file (DOCX) in the first place so that it converts into a nicely formatted EPUB? I need help to overcome these issues. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give a reference to IngramSpark standards

Comment: Also note that IngramSpark is not the only way to get an ebook to Amazon - see Amazon KDP

Comment: Sure. Please see: https://help.lightningsource.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021142012-eBook-Interior-ePUB-File-Creation-Requirements?source=search&auth_token=%E2%80%A6
What is Amazon KDP? Is it Kindle Create software? It does not support Persian language, as far as I know.

Comment: Also please see IngramSpark File Creation Standards here: https://www.ingramspark.com/hubfs/downloads/file-creation-guide.pdf

Comment: Please see page 6:
eBook File Submission Requirements
ebook Interior File
• EPUB (formatted as .epub)
• Format: EPUB 3.0 required. We cannot accept enhanced EPUB 3 files at this time.
• We follow the industry IDPF spec on EPUB formats. You can find more information at http://idpf.org/epub.
• All EPUBS must be compliant with the most up-to-date validation. You can use the following validation
site to confirm compliance - http://validator.idpf.org/
I believe Calibre with your comments using DOCX can help with creating Persian EPUB but I need help to develop it with IngramSpark guide.

Comment: This site is not for general guidance it is for asking a question that has a specific answer - so if you have a reproducable issue that you need to understand ten that would be on topic here.

Comment: I asked the reproduceable issue: How to reproduce an EPUB file with formats specified in a DOCX file? I believe answering the following would help with this: 
1) How to setup Word DOCX file to be correctly converted into nicely formatted EPUB file?
2) What are the correct parameters in Calibre - in its "Convert filename" - when converting DOCX to EPUB?
3) Besides Calibre what is/are applications which produce EPUB files in Persian Language.
If I get answers to the above, then I should be OK. 
Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: If the above can't be answered in this forum, please let me know which forum is the right one. Thanks. I am new to all these and trying to learn. I am not doing these things as a job or for profit.